# Codeigniter can you tell me about MY_Controller.php and directory structure?

Tags: codeigniter

I am trying to learn more about CI. Yesterday I tried to implement MY_Controller.php. I read the instructions in user guide But I could not get what is the advantage of it? And one more thing I did not understand the idea use it. 
I have written application/core/MY_Controller.php

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

  protected $data = array();

  function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
  }

  function render_page($view) {
    //do this to don't repeat in all controllers...
    $this->load->view('templates/header', $this->data);
    //menu_data must contain the structure of the menu...
    //you can populate it from database or helper

    $this->load->view($view, $this->data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer', $this->data);
  }
}
```

This my home controller application/controllers/home.php

```
class Home extends  MY_Controller  {

        public function view($page = 'home')
        {
         $this->load->helper('text');
            $this->data['records']= $this->services_model->getAll();

            if ( ! file_exists(APPPATH.'/views/pages/'.$page.'.php'))
            {
                // Whoops, we don't have a page for that!
                show_404();
            }

            $data['title'] = ucfirst($page); // Capitalize the first letter


              $this->render_page('pages/'.$page)
}
}
```

and my view is in in my application/views/pages/home.php.
config/routes.php:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'home/view';
$route['(:any)'] = 'home/view/$1';
```

Now I get 404 error. My questions are:

1) why do I get 404 error?
2) if I add the about page, am I supposed to  add a new controller or use the home controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**MY_Controller Controller  put into the application/core folder** 
Then use

**MY_Controller** folder path application/core/MY_Controller.php

**Home Controller ** folder path application/controllers/Home.php

Answer (score 0):

class Home extends  MY_Controller

to

class Home extends  CI_Controller

Answer (score 0):

1. The reason you're getting a 404 is, you did not have an index function. CodeIgniter by default loads the index function when a controller is called.
2. It doesn't really matter, but I would suggest you to open a new controller.

Comment: Before using my_Controller.php I was using pages controller . Again I did not use index as a function but I got the views ? are you sure?

Answer (score 0):

It is now working. I fixed by a clean directory structure. But i cant manage to see template/header and footer in the source code.